# JPA get result list order by selected columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a native query

```
searchSql = "Select  firstname,lastname from students order by id desc"
```

and then i do

```
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(searchSql);
    List<Map<String, Object>> results = query.getResultList();
```

Now if i print the results with KEYS

```
  List<String>headers = new ArrayList<>();
  for(String header : results.get(0).keySet()){
          headers.add(header);
  }
```

i get random order of the column names.
How can i get the exact order as in the select statement ?
LinkedHashMap should be the answer but i get class cast exceptions... Any generic ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked if `LinkedHashMap` causes the randomness of columns:

```
@Test
public void linkedHashMap() {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(integer -> {
        map.put(
            String.valueOf(integer), 
            integer
        );
    });

    for (String val : map.keySet()){
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

but instead it prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

The randomness seems to be a limitation of Hibernate, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279361/how-to-generate-table-using-hibernate-in-a-specific-column-sequence?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: that is since 10 years ? something must have been done to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If simply changing the signature to `List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();` does NOT work, then you can give a shot at `SqlResultSetMapping`. That way, the implicit map insertion would be avoided and order would be maintained I guess (I am not 100% sure, needs to be tested)

See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html.

Comment: the query is dynamic configurable from DB, so SqlResultSetMapping cannot be implemented. I need Column Names as well so List<Object[]> cannot be done.

Comment: [0]th element would be firstname and [1]st element would be lastname

Comment: If query is dynamic, then also you could implement a simple 'order knowing' code by parsing the sql select parameters, before it gets executed

Comment: Yes, finally i ended up just parsing the select sql params though its not 100% safe since query might be anything from simple to complex with many sub selects and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. it helped me to use `JdbcTemplate.queryForList()`
This solution will return you columns in right order as in the select statement if you don't need to serialize your result query to entity.

For example your repository will look like this:

```
@Repository
public class SiebelRepository {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> executeSqlScript(String sqlScript) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sqlScript);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).